# Storing JsonObject into JsonArray & JsonException error message

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, json

I am having some problem when trying to return the data fetched from MySQL as JSON in my Java Web Service:

```
public String getAllEvent() {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb", "root", "root");

        PreparedStatement statement = con
                .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM event");
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

        while (result.next()) {
            JSONObject eventInfo = new JSONObject();
            eventInfo.put("eventID", result.getString("eventID"));
            eventInfo.put("eventName", result.getString("eventName"));
            eventInfo.put("eventDesc", result.getString("eventDesc"));
            eventInfo.put("eventDate", result.getString("eventDate"));
            eventInfo.put("eventTime", result.getString("eventTime"));
            eventInfo.put("eventX", result.getString("eventX"));
            eventInfo.put("eventY", result.getString("eventY"));
            eventInfo.put("eventBy", result.getString("eventBy"));
            jsonArray.put(eventInfo);
        }
        String jsonStr = jsonArray.toString();
        return jsonStr;
    }

    catch (JSONException je) {
        return null;
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
    }

    return jsonArray.toString();
}
```

There are two errors message, one is at the *jsonArray.put(eventInfo);* with error message:

```
The method put(JSONObject) is undefined for the type JSONArray
```

The other one was with the JSONException:

```
JSONException cannot be resolved to a type
```

Any ideas? I've to import json-simple-1.1.jar into my project as external libraries, if not the JSONObject will get an error message of unresolved type.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples

Comment: Sorry but how do I implement it into my codes?

Comment: Could you then provide me the link for json library? Because I only managed to found json-simple library online

Comment: Looks to me like this is the `org.json` library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've imported the wrong library. You're writing code for the [org.json](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) library, not json-simple.

The link above will take you to the Maven repo, from which you can import into your project if you're using Maven, or just download the jar if not.

Comment: But do you have any idea why the method above is causing a faculty in my web service?

Comment: @IWasSoLost I can't see anything obviously wrong. I think you'd need to post that as a separate question, with some more details.

Comment: Can you please help me take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26715533/faculty-service-in-apache-tomcat-webservice