# Faulty Service in Apache Tomcat WebService

Tags: java, sql, json, web-services, tomcat

I am getting faulty services in my apache tomcat web service after adding this method in the web service:

```
public String getAllEvent() {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb", "root", "root");

        PreparedStatement statement = con
                .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM event");
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

        while (result.next()) {
            JSONObject eventInfo = new JSONObject();
            eventInfo.put("eventID", result.getString("eventID"));
            eventInfo.put("eventName", result.getString("eventName"));
            eventInfo.put("eventDesc", result.getString("eventDesc"));
            eventInfo.put("eventDate", result.getString("eventDate"));
            eventInfo.put("eventTime", result.getString("eventTime"));
            eventInfo.put("eventX", result.getString("eventX"));
            eventInfo.put("eventY", result.getString("eventY"));
            eventInfo.put("eventBy", result.getString("eventBy"));
            jsonArray.put(eventInfo);
        }
        String jsonStr = jsonArray.toString();
        return jsonStr;
    }

    catch (JSONException je) {
        return null;
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
    }

    return jsonArray.toString();
}
```

For this method, I am passing the data retrieved from database into JSON. After I added it, when I run the web service on server, I am getting this error message:

```
Faculty Services:
C:\Users\Desktop\Eclipse EE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\SplashWebService\WEB-INF\services\SplashWebService
```

The web service runs perfectly again after I removed this method. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you rename the method7

Comment: @StanislavL Unfortunately, no luck. The faculty services message is still there. There were no errors for the codes though

Comment: Do you mean *faulty* services? I have no idea what a faculty service is (and I used to work at a university).

Comment: @chiastic-security Yeah, sorry. It was a typo error :)

Comment: Nope. But is the method completing without giving an exception? Can you show us what the JSON it returns looks like? How many rows? (If it's lots, you might hit some limit in terms of size or transmission time.)

Comment: So far my database only have two rows of records and yeah, it's completing without giving exception, I assumed as I don't see anything in console. How do I print the JSON? Sorry I am quite new to this as I used to work with C#.

Comment: Where's/what's the error message?

Comment: can you put the stacktrace in the question?